# How do I open a port on Cisco PIX 506E firewall

Tags: networking, cisco

We have a Cisco PIX 506E VPN/firewall for our network (e.g. 50.197.160.20 is public IP of the Cisco PIX). I have a database engine running on a PC in my private network behind the Cisco PIX 506E. I want to allow an external application on the internet (in Cloud) to access my on premises database (e.g. 192.168.0.100:14333). So, I am setting up a Stunnel. I need to have a port opened on my Cisco PIX 506E for the Stunnel. What commands can I use to open a port ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Will need your existing PIX configuration to give exact commands.

Comment: Hi Abu, are there specific commands you were looking for? I am not sure if I were allowed to send over the complete config file. Thanks,

Comment: anything that has 'nat' in the statement will help.

Comment: Here are the statements with "nat" in them. Many thanks. --------access-list inside_outbound_nat0_acl permit ip any 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.224

nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_outbound_nat0_acl
nat (inside) 10 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0 0

isakmp nat-traversal 20

Comment: access-list inside_outbound_nat0_acl permit ip any 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.224

Comment: nat (inside) 0 access-list inside_outbound_nat0_acl

Comment: nat (inside) 10 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0 0

Comment: isakmp nat-traversal 20

Comment: OK, are there any statements that have word 'static' or 'global' in them?

Comment: No static. One global. global (outside) 10 interface

Comment: That makes it tricky. You are already using the Interface address for your Inside clients to access the internet. If you have another Public IP address from ISP, we can add static entry to open port for Stunnel using the second Public IP address. PIX is an old device, and I have never configured it to do what you are looking for.

Comment: We do have another public IP. Let's say it is 50.197.160.22. What commands can we use ? Many thanks.

Comment: I added it as answer, since comments are getting too long. If you have any questions, post to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information in comments.

```
static (inside,outside) 192.168.0.100 50.197.160.22 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0
```

Then create an access-list for to open port from outside.

```
access-list outside_in permit tcp host IpOfYourExternalHost host 192.168.0.100 eq 14333
```

Apply this to your outside interface.

```
access-group outside_in in interface outside
```

Comment: What is "YourExternalHost" in "IpOfYourExternalHost"? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The IP Address of external application in the Cloud that will be connecting to your Database over the Internet.

Comment: Thank you so much Abu. I will give it  a try.

Comment: When I execute the following command, I got a message like"Type help or ? to get a list of available commands"--


static (inside,outside) 192.168.0.100 50.197.160.22 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0

Comment: Sorry, I take it back I forgot to run conf t first.. I was able to run the commands. But it does not work.

Comment: Run show xlate and show conn to verify your settings. Also, do show logg to see any messages.

Comment: A question along the same line: What if I want to do 1-to-1 NAT, i.e. a public IP mapped to a private IP? For example, 50.197.160.22 is NATed to 192.168.0.100. What commands can I use ?

Comment: The static command does one to one NAT.

static (inside,outside) 192.168.0.100 50.197.160.22 netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0

Comment: I ran the recommended commands. I also ran the following. 

access-list outside_in permit tcp any host 50.197.160.22
access-group outside_in in interface outside

Comment: But I cannot ping the public IP. It says "request timeout".

Comment: Run show xlate and show conn to verify your settings. Also, do show logg to see any messages.

Comment: What do I look for in those files ? Thanks.

Comment: The IP Address you used to NAT. Post results.